# onClick called on second Click when :active is set on img

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically what I want to achieve is an clickable image with an active state. 
When the image is clicked something should happen and while it is pressed (active) it should display another image.

```js
document.getElementById("scrollbox-table-nav-softer").addEventListener("click", tableNavSofterOnClick);

function tableNavSofterOnClick(){
    //doStuff..
}
```

```css
#scrollbox-table-nav-softer{
    max-height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#scrollbox-table-nav-softer:active{
    content: url("https://www.joomlack.fr/images/demos/demo2/on-top-of-earth.jpg"); 
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn05.branchez-vous.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/bge2-800x410.jpg" id="scrollbox-table-nav-softer"/>
```

The problem is that when the page is loaded the first click on that element does nothing (the onClick method is not called). On the second click it works as intended (image changes when clicked and the onClick method is executed).

What causes the first click to malfunction?

EDIT:
I managed to fix this issue by adding a class to the CSS :active block like so:

```
#scrollbox-table-nav-softer:active .elementActive{
    content: url("../img/button_softer_active.png"); 
}
```

I dont know how or why... but it works now as intended. If someone can explain this to me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix:
You need to change image src on **onmouseup** and **onmousedown** events:

```
<img 

onmousedown="document.getElementById('scrollbox-table-nav-softer').src='your_image_1.jpg'"

onmouseup="document.getElementById('scrollbox-table-nav-softer').src='your_image.jpg'" 

src="your_image.jpg"  

id="scrollbox-table-nav-softer"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xcmqkcba/1/

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById(...)` you can also use `this` in this case. [I've updated the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xcmqkcba/2/) to represent this change.

Comment: I have tried your approach but it seems the mousedown event is only fired when a longer mouse-press has occured. The only change I made to your solution is that I set the eventlisteners in JavaScript (Because thats a requirement). Is this the problem?

Comment: @Piotr. That shouldn't be an issue. You can use `addEventListener` on the `img` if you need to. The reason why it _seems_ as if the event is only fired after a 'long-press' is because the browser will only start downloading once the `mousedown` event is fired. Until `your_image_1.jpg` is actually downloaded, the `src` won't be changed. You can verify this in the network tab in your browsers dev-tools